# I want remove blue picture on my blog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

[image: x enter image description here x]

See above photo its only showing blue

Below my html template

It's my site : https://pdfpaper.blogspot.com

I'm using Sora Coupen Free Version Template

Anyone tell me how can I remove the blue covered picture..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] & **[mcve]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspect on the color of blue which you don't want and remove this

```
 background: rgba(40, 116, 240, 0.61);
```

in your css.

Comment: Your are tha Genius ...Its Working Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'background' style attribute for the selector ".offer-badge" in your css.
This will work

Answer (score 0):

- Go to **Theme** > **Edit HTML**
- click anywhere inside your code and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> from keyboard
- search for `background: rgba(40, 116, 240, 0.61);` and remove it

Comment: Thanks I have already finished